# How to create gensim word2vec model using pre trained word vectors?

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec, text-analysis, word-embedding

I have created word vectors using a distributed word2vec algorithm. Now I have words and their corresponding vectors. How to build a gensim word2vec model using these words and vectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if you created word2vec model using `gensim` or some other tools but if understand your question correctly you want to just load the word2vec model using gensim. This is done in the following way:

```
import gensim
w2v_file = codecs.open(WORD2VEC_PATH, encoding='utf-8')
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(w2v_file, binary=True)  # or binary=False if the model is not compressed
```

If, however, what you want to do is to train word2vec model from scratch (i.e. from raw text) using purely `gensim` here is a [tutorial on how to train word2vec model using gensim](https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Could you please provide sample w2v_file or help me generate that format? I have the word and its vectors in a line separated by spaces and words are separated by lines. Thank you. @sophros

Comment: Have you tried the following approach?
`from gensim.models import word2vec
model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('path/to/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=False)`

The important part is the `binary=False`.

Comment: It did help me, thank you. I trained my corpus using Microsoft multiverso. Now I can use load_word2vec_format to create my model.